# What are the pros and cons of P2P mining pools?

Tags: mining-pools, p2pool, majority-attack

I've heard P2P mining pools are the answer to the current threat of mining pools controlling 51% of Bitcoin's hashing power.  Is this true or not true?  Does anyone have a supporting or critical assessment of P2P mining pools? What are the trade offs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the trade offs? P2P mining pools?

Answer (score 3):

P2Pool allows individual miners to band together and find blocks with the reward being shared directly with the miners who participated in finding the block.  If you didn't contribute a pool share during a round, you wouldn't receive a payment for a block found by the round.  The pool has a lower difficulty than the network but greater than an individual miner.  That is, your miner can be submitting shares to the pool but you won't get a pool share unless one of your shares has a difficulty greater than the pool difficulty.  When somebody submits a share with a difficulty greater than the network difficulty, a block is found and everybody who contributed at least one pool share gets part of the reward.

So the trade-off is a high variance since you only get paid if you were participating at the time a block is found and you contributed a pool share.  And finding a block itself is highly variable since it depends on the total hash power of the pool (luck also plays a large role).

Depending on your hash power, you could run your own p2pool or join a p2pool set up by somebody else.  The advantage of joining a common p2pool is it increases your chance to contribute a pool share and thus share in the block reward.

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage to shifting miners from using a centralized pool to P2P pools is that it may spread out the hashing power across multiple independent groups - balkanization of the hash compute power. This doesn't solve the problem, it just disrupts it slightly.

A P2P pool is still a collective effort working together as a single block mining entity.  There may not be a central server involved in a P2P pool, but the pool is still collecting transactions and creating a block to add to the blockchain.

If a P2P pool is large enough to produce 51% of the global network hash output, the pool would have the same potential to disrupt blockchain transactions as any other pool - if someone with malicious intent were able to gain control of the block creation process.

So, while a P2P pool might change where the block is created (central vs super node vs any node) and therefore the point of attack, shifting everyone from GHash to *one* P2P pool won't change the 51% threat.